# Appending a dataframe to the right of another one with the same columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different dataframes with the same column names:

eg.

```
     0   1   2
0   10  13  17
1   14  21  34
2   68  32  12

     0   1   2 
0   45  56  32
1    9  22  86
2   55  64  19
```

I would like to append the second frame to the right of the first one while continuing the column names from the first frame. The output would look like this:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0  10  13  17  45  56  32
1  14  21  34   9  22  86
2  68  32  12  55  64  19
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pd.concat` first and then reset the columns.

```
In [1108]: df_out = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

In [1109]: df_out.columns = list(range(len(df_out.columns)))

In [1110]: df_out
Out[1110]: 
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0  10  13  17  45  56  32
1  14  21  34   9  22  86
2  68  32  12  55  64  19
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not `join`:

```
>>> df=df.join(df_,lsuffix='_')
>>> df.columns=range(len(df.columns))
>>> df
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0  10  13  17  45  56  32
1  14  21  34   9  22  86
2  68  32  12  55  64  19
>>>
```

`join` is your friend, i use `lsuffix` (could be `rsuffix` too) to ignore error for saying duplicate columns.